# Easy way to print out first found answer and exit a loop

Tags: python

Im doing project euler problem 5 and I just need the first number my loop finds (because it's the smallest) and I cant seem to find a way to break out of the loop when it finds the first result. Tried using break but it just doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
"""2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"""


dividers = [11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] # if it divides by 20 we can cross out 2, 4, 5, 10; 19 is prime;
# if it divides by 18 we can remove 3, 6, 9; 17 is prime; if by 16 then 8; if by 14 then 7; 13 is prime; 11 is prime

for x in range(20, 999999999, 20):  # step has to be 20 so the number can be divisible by 20
    if all(x % n == 0 for n in dividers):
        print(x)
```

Result:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 "/home/michal/Desktop/Project Euler/Problem5.py"
232792560
465585120
698377680
931170240

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Tried with break but it just prints out all the number divisible by 20.

```
dividers = [11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] # if it divides by 20 we can cross out 2, 4, 5, 10; 19 is prime;
# if it divides by 18 we can remove 3, 6, 9; 17 is prime; if by 16 then 8; if by 14 then 7; 13 is prime; 11 is prime

for x in range(20, 999999999, 20):  # step has to be 20 so the number can be divisible by 20
    if all(x % n == 0 for n in dividers):
        break
    print(x)
```

Comment: `break` should do exactly what you want. How exactly have you tried using it?

Comment: no clue how to format my code in a comment so you can see indents... Just gonna edit my main post

Comment: look carefully at the differences in indentation between your examples with and without `break`, and make sure you understand how indentation works in python.

Comment: move `print(x)` outside of the for loop

Comment: Thank you guys, works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Just had to move my print(x) outside of the for loop as mentioned by Luke.
Here is working code:

```
dividers = [11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] # if it divides by 20 we can cross out 2, 4, 5, 10; 19 is prime;
# if it divides by 18 we can remove 3, 6, 9; 17 is prime; if by 16 then 8; if by 14 then 7; 13 is prime; 11 is prime

for x in range(20, 999999999, 20):  # step has to be 20 so the number can be divisible by 20
    if all(x % n == 0 for n in dividers):
        break
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making that into a function:

```
def project_Euler_Problem5(dividers):
     for x in range(dividers[:-1], 999999999, dividers[:-1]):
        if all(x % n == 0 for n in dividers):
            return x
```

It'd have the added benefit of making all of your other Euler solutions ordered when you go through them (and keep the older ones).

Fun fact: You can also start from 2520 instead of 20, since you won't find the answer before the first part of the answer is reached.

Edit: When making large ranges (like from 20 to 999999999), I'd recommend using xrange() as it'll make the code run a bit faster (especially if you do this consistently).

Edit: The function is just packaging your code. If for some reason you'd like to abstract it to any number of divisors I'd change it to reflect that.